# Flex 4: Garbage Collection doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, garbage-collection, flex4

I have a TitleWindow component that I'm displaying via PopUpManager.addPopUp(). When I close the component, I'm calling the closePopUp Event which sets the object's variable to null, as follows:

```
// application
private var myObject:MyObject;

private function openPopUp():void
{
    myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.addEventListener('closePopUp', closePopUp);
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(myObject, this, true);
}

private function closePopUp(e:Event):void
{
    myObject = null;
}
```

However in debug mode I can see myObject being set to null, but the memory usage doesn't decrease. When I open the component again, the memory usage remains the same as before.

I would have thought when the myObject variable is set to null, GC recycles the object and frees up memory. Any idea why this is not happening?

Comment: in debug mode you can try to call System.gc() to force garbage collection (but not in release).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the event listener, I think having it hanging on there will prevent the GC from collecting your object.

Comment: No, that's a myth. See [here](http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290298/actionscript-3-do-self-event-listeners-prevent-an-object-from-being-garbage-col).

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collection in Flash Player is not an exact science and works a little different to what most people expects... To summarize it, it only frees up memory when it needs more. These articles explain it with more detail:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html
http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html
http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/garbage_collection_and_memory.html

Also, as Dein says, the event listeners are the most common cause for memory leaks in Flash. You have to be very careful and always try to remove them.