# Actionscript 3: Do self event listeners prevent an object from being garbage collected?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection, event-listener

I know that event listeners and references to an object will prevent the garbage collector from dealing with objects.  My question is, will an event listener placed on an object, listening to the same object, prevent that object from being garbage collected?

I ask because it seems like this is happening to me.  I am breaking all my references to an object but I am still seeing traces when its timer goes off.  At the same time, it seems like this should not prevent the collection because it would create allocated but unreferenceable memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, but.

The AVM2 garbage collector is *supposed* to find unreachable objects. But because garbage collection is non-deterministic, it's very hard to rely on or even test this behaviour -- it could be that the garbage collector is working perfectly, but not bothering to run the mark-and-sweep since you have enough RAM free.

It's a good idea to **remove event listeners when you're done with the object**, even if they're from the object itself (i.e. circular references). Why is this a good idea? Because **you never know when the garbage collector is going to run**. If you want deterministic behaviour, always remove listeners in a deterministic fashion, *especially* for time-sensitive events like TIMER and ENTER_FRAME, otherwise you're creating a race condition between your listeners running and the garbage collector running. The garbage collector only runs periodically.

In general, if you want to attach event listeners without creating an additional reference to the object, pass true to the `useWeakReference` parameter of `addEventListener()`. If you want to stop receiving the events right away, though, you'll still need to manually detach your event listeners as soon as you're done with the object.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the events still firing.  I'm much more concerned about the memory getting freed up at some point.  However, I do see that the benefit here in the CPU department could be substantial.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will stop the GC from cleaning up your object. A hacky way to try to prevent this is to use weak references when adding listeners.

```
 myobj.addEventListener(Event.EVENT, eventHandler, false, 0, true);
```

The last true flag will set the listener to use a weak object reference.

Best practice would be to keep track and always remove any active listeners before nulling your object.

Check out this great blog post for more info on this topic

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I read that article but I'm still a little confused.  When the garbage collector does the mark sweeping phase, where will it mark my object at?  Is there a list of event listeners somewhere that gives a references to the objects that the events are attached to/listening to?

Comment: When you add the listener to an object you're adding a ref to it

Comment: -1. This does NOT stop the GC from collecting your instance. http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Yes, hence why his object will not be GC'd. The object with the listener also contains the method being called. Using a weak ref will stop this from happening, seems like this is the perfect use case for it?

Comment: So in the case of of reference based garbage collecting, the object will never be GCed because it is its own listener and dispatcher.  But, on the account of mark sweeping it will, because nothing involved has a reference path to it from the document root.  The big problem here is that it looks like most people, myself 45 minutes ago included, don't know about the mark sweeping based garbage collection.

Comment: @AlexN. Best practice is to keep track of and remove all your listeners. One easy way would be to create a proxy class that adds all listeners and objects to a dictionary as well as adding the ref. This way you can then loop through this and be sure that all listeners are removed.

Comment: Best practice is just to write readable and manageable code and remove listeners yourself, not only before you want to prep for garbage collection, but more importantly *when they're no longer needed*.

Comment: Note, the documentation says that the EVENT LISTENER will not be collected, not the object. So your answer is half-right. The event listener will not get collected unless you use weak reference, but the listener will not prevent the target object from being collected.

Comment: See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()

Comment: In circular references, the event listener IS the object! Unless you're producing literally thousands of objects per seconds (as in game programming), waste time managing listeners that won't cause a memory leak?