# Flex: Does using "new" remove event listeners?

Tags: apache-flex, memory, garbage-collection

I'm having a memory management problem and I'm wondering if it's related to how I add and remove event listeners.  Let's say I have something like the following in a function:

```
ns = new NetStream();
addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,handleStatus);
```

If I were to call it again, does the fact that I'm recreating ns with "new" remove any listeners that were attached to the object?

Answer (score 2):

No, the new keyword will not mark former instances for garbage collection as the event listener attached to the old instance of ns retains the object in memory.

Assuming you mean:

```
ns = new NetStream();
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handleStatus);
```

Instance of `ns` is now retained by the event listener itself.

[ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform: addEventListener()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29)

> If you no longer need an event listener, remove it by calling
>   removeEventListener(), or memory problems could result. Event
>   listeners are not automatically removed from memory because the
>   garbage collector does not remove the listener as long as the
>   dispatching object exists (unless the useWeakReference parameter is
>   set to true).

Ideally remove the event listener when you dispose the object:

```
ns.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handleStatus);
```

Otherwise, you could implement your event listeners using weak references:

```
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handleStatus, false, 0, true);
```

Weak reference determines whether the reference to the listener is strong or weak. A strong reference (the default) prevents your listener from being garbage-collected. A weak reference does not.

Comment: No, an object may be garbage-collected even if it has event listeners registered. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290298/actionscript-3-do-self-event-listeners-prevent-an-object-from-being-garbage-col), for example. There's no need to remove event listeners to dispose of an object.

Comment: It's suboptimal to rely on mark and sweep garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `ns = new NetStream();` may or may not result in the eventual removal of event listeners. If the variable `ns` held a reference to another object before the assignment, and this was the last reference to that object, the garbage collector may at some point destroy the object. The event listeners attached to the old object won't affect its destruction. If an object is destroyed, all of its event listeners are removed, and, if the aren't any remaining references to the listeners, the listeners can be destroyed, too (this only applies to inner functions, member functions are never destroyed).

Note that it might take some time until the garbage collector destroys objects. So even an unreferenced object will continue to fire events. This is why it's usually a good idea to remove event listeners if you're done with an object.